# Extend/Merge/Share Context Menus from custom control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I use a custom control in multiple views. In that custom control I defined a context menu with common MenuItems, that need to be available in different views. Each view than can extend that context menu by their own MenuItems.

How do I accomplish this? I can only replace the exsting context menu, but not extending it.

I read about merging context menus here: http://wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html.
But it doesn't show how to merge with the existing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use resources. You define all the menu items in the window/usercontrol's resource, and then reference them with the key of the menu items.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <MenuItem Header="Add sub-folder"
              Command="{Binding FolderNewCmd}"
              x:Key="AddFolderMenu">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="/YourAssemblyNameSpace;component/Images/16/abc.png"
                   Width="16"
                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor">
            </Image>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    ...  <--other menu items-->
 <Window.Resources>
```

When you want to reference this menu item in a menu (e.g. a context menu):

```
<TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="AddFolderMenu" />
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="OtherMenuItemInResource" />
        ...
</TreeView.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Where do you exactly "reference" them? In the ContextMenu tag? As StaticResource? Please give an example, thanks!

Comment: hope this is more specific, I use treeview as an example.

Comment: Man, I always wonder how to put StaticResource in place like that. My IntelliSense doesn't support "StaticResource" inside "TreeView.ContextMenu", so I never saw that option :-)